# In SQL Server with property count to select dynamic result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server and tried to fetch the data for a given scenario but didn't succeed. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Scenario is :

1. **if cont is 1 just simply return the USER id.**
2. **if cont is greater then 1 then return the user which have enabled='01'**
3. **if cont is greater then 1 and more then 1 is enabled='01' for that user then return first user in the table based on alphabetical order.**

**Structure and sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE TableA 
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  lan varchar(20), 
  user varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('a','1');
INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('b','2');
INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('c','3');
INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('d','4');
INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('e','5');
INSERT INTO TableA (lan, user) VALUES ('f','6');

CREATE TABLE TableB (
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  fuser VARCHAR(10),
  enabled VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO TableB (fuser) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('2','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('3','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser) VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('4','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('5','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('5','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser, enabled) VALUES ('5','01');
INSERT INTO TableB (fuser) VALUES ('5');
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT LAN, USER AS USER, COUNT(fuser) AS cont, FUSER as FUSER,
CASE  
  WHEN COUNT(fuser)=4  THEN FUSER
  WHEN COUNT(fuser)=2 THEN FUSER
  WHEN COUNT(fuser)=1  THEN FUSER
  ELSE null
END as result
            from TableA
            LEFT JOIN TableB
            ON trim(lower(USER))=trim(lower(FUSER))
      GROUP BY USER
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d47f6/4

Comment: What grouping columns do you need to count fuser for?   In your fiddle you are counting fuser and grouping by fuser, which doesn't make any sense.   If you are counting fuser, you need to group by something else.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle as per your comment.

Comment: @anand Please also update your output

Comment: Given your sample data in your fiddle, can you post your desired results?

Comment: your fiddle uses auto_increment which is mysql syntax and your tag saya sql-server and you query is not needed if you have provided the fiddle but it's good that you provided it, just show your desired and actual output if possible

Comment: @anand It is really a good thing that you did a SQL Fiddle demo to help you contributors, but next time please include the table structure and queries in the question. (Just in case, SQL Fiddle could go offline, or the fiddle could be deleted)

Comment: Thanks @Pred next time. I will take care about it.

Comment: highlighting your question again or simply writing the desired output will not help. Show some form of tabular result which you desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @temp table ( nofouser int, id int )

insert into @temp 
select distinct count(t1.[user]) over (partition by t1.[user]) as noofuser,t1.id 
from TableA t1 
  LEFT JOIN TableB t2 on t1.[user]=t2.fuser

select [user] 
from @temp r 
   inner join TableA on TableA.id=r.id 
where nofouser=1

select distinct [user] 
from @temp r 
   inner join TableA on TableA.id=r.id 
   inner join TableB on TableB.fuser=TableA.[user] 
where nofouser>1 
  and TableB.[enabled]=1

select * 
from ( 
  select count([user]) over (partition by [user]) as enableduser,
         [user] 
 from @temp r 
     inner join TableA on TableA.id=r.id 
     inner join TableB on TableB.fuser=TableA.[user] 
     where nofouser>1 and TableB.[enabled]=1 
 ) s 
 where enableduser>1
```